# Undefined problem when fetching and array

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a .json array that contains objects, I fetch that array from the .json and save it to an array in my .js file.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Burton Family Tree",
    "price": 600,
    "img": "url"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Burton Mystery",
    "price": 700,
    "img": "url"
  },
 .
 .
 .
]
```

When I use the complete fetched array it works perfectly but when I want to use just one element of this array it shows an undefined error for the whole object itself and each attribute of it.

```
let products = [];
let productsURL = url;

async function loadProducts() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(productsUrl);
    const productsJSON = await response.json();
    for (const item of productsJSON) {
      products.push({
        name: item.name,
        price: item.price,
        img: item.img,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

loadProducts();

console.log(products) -> works fine

console.log(products[0]) -> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined

console.log(products[0].img) -> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')`
```

Comment: `loadProducts()` is an `async` function but you didn't `await` it (or, alternatively, follow it with `.then()`).

Comment: `console.log(products) -> works fine` - but works _different_ from how you think it does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static#logging_objects